# Change the hint size when is a email input and is empty

Tags: android, material-components-android

I need to get the placeholder (called hint as I've been reading), to get a bigger font when the input is still empty. I need to make the modification in the code, because it only applies for the email inputs. This is the original state:
[image: Original text size]

The solutions I have found helps me to do this:

[image]

The font hint font gets bigger only when the input is active, but I need to do it when is not (when the screen loads). By the way, I have tried

```
textInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.hint_label_special_style);
```

Being the style

```
<style name="hint_label_special_style">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/fontExtraLarge</item>
</style>
```

that gets me the second picture effect, and this:

```
valueField.setTextSize(40.0f);
```

Just gets the font size bigger when I write in the input.

I am using material 1.1.0 and SDK version 29.0.3. If you need more specifications, I can give it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default hint text appear when field is empty and the hint size is as big as the `textSize` , just set it in `EditText` tag .

Comment: I've tried that, with 
valueField.setTextSize(40.0f);
but, the hint size remains the same, and when I select the input, only then shows the size of 40 (the 40 is just to notice the change)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was the material library version. It seems that the material 1.1.0 had an issue when changing programatically properties like the textSize, but when I upgraded it to com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0 the Mustafa solution worked perfectly.
In case anyone has the same problem, here is the release page of this version, to check how could affect your project this update:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.2.0